# Returning index with list comprehension

Tags: python

I have two lists as:

`main = [[1,2,3,4],[3,1,2,4],[4,3,1,2],[1,2,3,4],...]`

and

`lookup = [[3,1,2,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,2],...]`

I want to return a list of indices where each element of main list is located in lookup list. Assume every unique row of main is included in lookup. For the visible part of the above example the result should be indices = `[2,0,2,1]`. List comprehension solutions are expected, since I already coded this with for loops.

P.S. Elaboration

`[1,2,3,4]`,`[3,1,2,4]`,`[4,3,1,2]`,`[1,2,3,4]` are lists in `main` list. For every list in `main` list, return the index for an exact match in `lookup` list. 1st list element of `main` which is `[1,2,3,4]` is at the index `1` of lookup list, 2nd is at the index `0`, 3rd is at `2` and last one is at `1`. This makes `indices=[2,0,2,1]`. Sorry for not asking cleaner way.

Comment: If you "already coded this with for loops" then where exactly are you getting stuck? syntactically, list comp are just a fancy for loop

Comment: Can you provide the solution with for loop ? It'll be easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: *since I already coded this with for loops...*, I don't see any code?

Comment: @ DeepSpace I'm looking for a neater way.

Comment: Elements in the lists must be unique!?

Comment: @colt.exe see my answer! I don't understand who downvoted my answer. It is exactly doing what you asked. Except it assumes that each element is unique in both lists

Comment: Could you change the value in `main` to a tuple.And change them to a dict,I think that's will be faster.

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741318/return-indices-of-list-of-lists-by-looking-up-another-list-with-list-comprehensi), where's your implementation and what's the specific *problem* with it? What exactly does *"neater"* mean? Have you *tried* writing a list comp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary with the unqiue values and their respective index using enumerate for the iterable "lookup".

```
main = [[1,2,3,4],[3,1,2,4],[4,3,1,2],[1,2,3,4]]
lookup = [[3,1,2,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,3,1,2]]

dic_lookup = {str(lst):i for i, lst in enumerate(lookup)}
lst_index = [dic_lookup.get(str(lst)) for lst in main]

print(lst_index)
#Out[5]: [1, 0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`result = [ main.index(e) for e in lookup ]`

#### Explanation:

`main.index(e)` looks for the first occurrence of `e` in `main` and returns its index. And the list comprehension does this for every element `e` in `lookup`.

Comment: Using `.index(...)` on every element will be very slow since it does a linear search. This will essentially be `O(N^2)`

Comment: @JoshuaNixon he wants a solution, not necessarily an optimized one.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you. He already did the solution using loops so he understand how to solve the problem. Now, All what he needs is the syntax using llist comprehension.

Comment: @theTinMan updated with explanation.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon for a large amount of small lists (like in a microbench) using index will outperform (significantly), because it avoids object initialization.  It's particularly bad in the case of the accpted answer, because of string conversion, and the example in the accepted answer is actually implemented very poorly.  I'm kind of wondering why nobody downvoted it.  How relevant that performance is for general context is subject to opinion, and requires real world data testing to be relevant.

Comment: TL;DR talking about performance here is subjective and its relevance contestable esp. without explicit (real world) context.  Granted the OP was asking for something subjective in of itself